# OpenXR FOV in Unity Editor too small for Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, openxr

I have a problem after switching from Unity integrated XR to Open XR when using Holoremoting. The Unity Editor FOV 29 deg, although the Hololens 2 FOV is 54 deg. [Unity Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pIDw.png) How can I increase the FOV of my Main Camera in Unity so it's the same as the actual Hololens 2 FOV through the visor? The FOV slider doesn't work once connected via Holographic Remoting. I want to see the same view in the Unity Game view as the user sees through the Hololens2 visor.

Unity: 2020.3.26f1

MRTK: 2.7.3

MR OpenXR Plugin: 1.2.1

Comment: Do you want it to be full of the Game window?

Comment: I want to see the same view in the Unity Game view as the user sees through the Hololens2 visor. Right now, I only see a small portion in the Game window. Eg. through the Hololens2, I see the blue cylinder in its entirety (screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

You can’t change the FOV. But you can modify the view size in Game window to show more content. I see you are using 16:9 Aspect. You can try Free Aspect.

[image: Free Aspect in Unity]

Comment: Unfortunately, I see less of what the Hololens 2 sees when I switch to Free Aspect. Looks like the view gets clipped when I switch to Free Aspect. I want to increase the FOV, not the resolution in the Unity Game View.

Comment: Currently, there is no way to increase the FOV. You can use [MRC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/mixed-reality-capture-overview) to see the content in HoloLens as a workaround.